# Interactive Brokers java api, Eclient::reqOpenOrders not working

Tags: java, trading

I am recently playing with IB trading java api. 
After meddling with the demo, some of the api works fine but some did not. 
I ran Eclient:: reqPnL, i have the call back as expected.
i ran Eclient::reqOpenOrders and Eclient::reqCompletedOrders, i got no response. To be accurate, Ewrapper::openOrderEnd was indeed invoked while Ewrapper::openOrder was not, and Ewrapper::completedOrdersEnd was invoked while completedOrders was not.
the tws software i installed is the latest one already, can not figure out why. 
Anyone can share your experience ? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

turns out if i update the api version, it works fine